# ModbusTCP protocol to an EthernetIP protocol c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, tcp, ethernet

can anyone explain how to implement the EthernetIP protocol based client driver

1. How to start
2. Any stack available
3. What is difference between TCP/IP and ethernetIP?Weather there is a
   major deviation during implementation.
4. Much appreciated if i get sample POC code for ethernetIP
   implementation.

I have knowledge on implementing TCP client.I have come across a guide on internet [EtherNet/IP Quick Start for Vendors Handbook](https://www.odva.org/Portals/0/Library/Publications_Numbered/PUB00213R0_EtherNetIP_Developers_Guide.pdf)

Note:Consider any device connected via a Ethernet cable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

EtherNet/IP is base on [CIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Industrial_Protocol)(Common Industrial Protocol)

You can reference this [specification](http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/ebook/763212/EIP-CIP-V2-1.0.pdf) to implement EtherNet/IP